# Cannot find module 'util.js' after command npm init on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed npm before and work with many projects along with express.js , but today I opened a folder and willing to start a new project. But after `npm init` command , it says `util.js` module not found.

I found this `util.js` file on this root directory `npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules`.

How to solve this issue?

> ```
> F:\Pulok\HabluTheGreatDoc\Projects\ReactApp\event-booking>npm init
> npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
> npm ERR! Cannot find module './util.js'
> npm ERR! Require stack:
> npm ERR! - C:\Users\Sabbir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpx\index.js
> npm ERR! - C:\Users\Sabbir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\init.js
> npm ERR! - C:\Users\Sabbir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
> npm ERR! - C:\Users\Sabbir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sabbir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-12T06_33_44_670Z-debug.log
> ```

---

**Edit:**

- npm version: `6.14.5`.
- node.js version: `v12.16.1`
- I have also tried running `npm cache clean --force` and `npm init --yes`, however I continue to get the same error message.

Comment: have you tried manually installing util globally, Though I think this is to do something with your node installation.

Comment: Are you attached to your node.js installation?  Just remove node.js and reinstall it.

Comment: I uninstall it from apps & feature, then download the latest version and reinstall

Comment: Have you tried to install NPM manually?

Comment: @PaulRumkin Yes, I tried with installing npm manually. But , problem not solved.